# Sorting item template when programmatically add HeaderText

Tags: asp.net

I have datagrid and inside this grid have template field. I add Header text progr. like this

```
gvData.HeaderRow.Cells(8).Text = "Hi"
```

But when I do this I can not sort this column when add SortExpression="Hi", i not have clickable header.

How can I do this

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this with CType(gvData.HeaderRow.Cells(8).Controls(0), WebControls.LinkButton).Text